# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found on newly installed Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, iwlwifi

Recently, I installed Ubuntu20.04 on my brand new laptop, but I cannot connect to wifi as it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found."

Following is some of the information that could help you to understand the issue better.

1. Wireless Adapter: Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz (Pre-installed when bought)
2. Laptop: Galaxy Book Flex 2

( *** I went to Samsung Service Center in case it was a hardware issue, but it turned out to be fine with the wireless adapter itself. ***)

3. OS: dual-booting with Windows 10 and Ubuntu20.04
4. Kernel version (`# uname -r`): 5.13.0-051300-generic
5. Driver firmware (saved in /lib/firmware): iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0.tgz

( *** Since my wireless adapter did not have the right Linux firmware when I first noticed this issue, I both upgraded my kernel from 5.8 to 5.13 and placed the latest driver in /lib/firmware and load the driver with the command #sudo modprobe iwlwifi ***)

6. Wireless performance on different OS: wifi works fine on Windows 10, but only on Ubuntu, from the get-go, it does not.
7. Other settings:

   disabled the "fast-boot" option on Windows

   disabled the "secure boot" from grub
8. Logs from useful commands

```
# rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

 

# modinfo iwlwifi

filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-051300-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-mr-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf4-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-mr-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-mr-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf4-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-63.ucode
srcversion:     CE3C196FF6EA02BF3E06B73
...alias...(I skipped it as it was too long and irrelevant.)
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.13.0-051300-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        13:F9:57:D9:18:E8:F0:25:0B:9E:94:9E:ED:41:11:91:FF:A3:41:4E
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      61:3A:01:89:8E:C3:4D:CE:50:5A:B4:C4:7D:73:C2:CD:12:C4:19:45:
        68:F6:DC:F0:8E:62:EB:74:FF:E3:57:0C:CF:86:27:8F:69:B4:16:07:
        FE:72:64:14:D3:AE:69:28:BE:9F:B3:91:9D:52:FD:60:95:55:51:D9:
        4D:47:2A:F3:31:9B:32:1B:8C:38:56:4E:DE:6F:02:1E:87:0D:4F:D1:
        B4:6B:7E:64:5C:D2:02:FE:FA:34:8A:C1:C7:5E:1B:EE:34:35:60:63:
        6D:5B:F2:65:90:43:BB:21:D4:54:97:F6:28:13:B5:6F:5A:49:21:0E:
        90:9B:96:26:29:8C:A2:3C:8E:A5:F6:B3:8E:83:6C:2C:5D:50:43:97:
        CF:C6:B5:95:2D:04:83:75:26:25:FD:60:76:C1:99:8A:BB:99:B1:15:
        EF:C2:46:C5:A6:ED:45:B2:BD:62:37:50:A6:70:F6:9A:EE:87:BD:0C:
        C6:56:16:90:F7:03:62:88:57:86:E6:9A:9C:C6:E0:46:D4:7D:B0:A1:
        02:DA:A8:BD:62:EB:20:0D:F1:C9:8D:E1:69:C3:61:4A:81:E4:52:56:
        96:E7:42:C5:ED:EF:48:5C:C7:E4:4C:25:38:B3:E3:F4:4C:B9:8D:F9:
        10:C3:6D:5B:5D:4E:75:84:C5:FF:3C:FD:0A:02:7C:93:DC:09:28:32:
        AD:6D:6E:48:54:BB:75:F3:2E:70:C2:00:1C:BC:A3:3D:80:EE:46:6A:
        79:E3:E3:5C:4C:69:F5:EC:92:72:DE:BD:32:C3:45:FF:E1:AD:B0:D6:
        A4:91:53:82:2B:B7:4E:82:FB:F3:D0:4E:86:BA:C5:D9:E6:8C:1E:D7:
        5C:3D:99:51:B4:10:74:46:AF:29:08:1D:F1:B4:59:B0:EB:0D:7E:FE:
        A9:B4:0B:BF:5E:A7:75:7E:77:C5:A4:D7:7A:F5:5B:D2:04:3D:98:ED:
        BA:79:E3:8A:6D:98:D5:F7:CA:28:3B:F1:BE:69:78:82:35:ED:7D:87:
        99:5F:E6:60:78:52:EA:4B:D0:4B:41:45:34:4B:16:94:F0:66:16:35:
        FA:7A:1B:CC:74:D9:BD:D3:99:A4:11:B0:B0:C5:0D:91:40:3C:24:67:
        8E:E8:12:7F:6F:86:BE:9B:D5:02:94:29:7F:44:3B:3E:E5:15:03:67:
        E4:5F:80:25:C4:A5:56:BB:AB:F6:8B:DB:A2:BF:CD:E3:45:A5:04:FD:
        F6:65:59:A9:E4:F4:83:91:9B:00:49:AE:23:5A:58:B1:A5:CA:07:5E:
        7E:05:CB:73:B4:1D:F0:FA:A0:50:0D:F5:C1:62:1C:7D:1C:BE:6C:12:
        70:EE:5A:0F:71:64:DC:C6:A7:C3:6D:46
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)



# lsmod | grep iwlwifi

iwlwifi 385024 0
cfg80211 897024 1 iwlwifi


# sudo lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 14.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
version: 20
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:603d1d4000-603d1d7fff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 2
logical name: bnep0
serial: fc:b3:bc:28:06:fd
capabilities: ethernet physical
configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.45 multicast=yes

# dmesg | grep iwlwifi

[ 2.197973] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[ 2.200456] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
[ 2.207538] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

For days, I have tried many approaches online, but none of them seems to work. Any piece of advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Best,

So

Comment: Please run: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04 for Galaxy Flex 2.