# Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 is not working on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

I'm trying to learn Linux and having trouble with wifi.  I am running Ubuntu 21.04 with 5.11.0-22-generic kernel.  I have no options under the network tab in settings for wifi as if my wifi card is not detected.  I have searched and tried just about every solution i could find on this forum and nothing seems to work.  I have downloaded the appropriate drivers from the Intel website and moved the files into the /lib/firmware directory as it says to do in the README file.  Wifi works fine when I boot into Windows.  Ubuntu is installed on an external SSD.  I'm not quite sure what all information is needed to troubleshoot this issue but I have provided what i have so far.  Thanks for the help.

```
lshw -C network
    *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:51254000-51257fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 2a:a7:a9:22:d6:f2
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.240.100 link=yes multicast=yes

dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.447426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.450352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)128.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.450579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)127.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.450595] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)126.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.450795] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)125.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.450987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)124.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)123.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451013] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)122.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)121.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451244] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)120.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)119.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)118.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451278] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)117.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451288] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)116.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)115.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451306] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)114.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)113.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)112.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)111.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)110.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451354] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)109.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451361] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)108.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451368] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)107.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451375] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)106.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451382] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)105.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451389] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)104.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)103.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)102.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)101.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)100.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)99.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451449] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)98.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)97.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451470] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)96.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451477] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)95.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)94.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451491] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)93.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451498] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)92.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451505] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)91.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451514] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)90.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451521] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)89.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)88.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451535] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)87.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451542] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)86.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451550] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)85.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451557] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)84.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451564] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)83.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451571] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)82.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451578] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)81.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451585] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)80.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)79.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)78.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451606] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)77.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451613] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)76.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451620] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)75.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451627] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)74.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)73.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)72.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451648] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)71.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)70.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)69.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)68.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451678] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)67.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)66.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451692] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)65.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)64.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451706] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)63.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451713] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)62.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451720] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)61.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)60.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)59.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)58.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)57.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451756] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)56.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)55.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451770] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)54.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451777] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)53.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451783] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451791] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451800] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451808] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451816] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)48.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451825] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)47.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)46.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451839] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)45.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451846] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)44.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451853] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)43.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451860] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)42.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451867] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)41.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)40.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)39.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)38.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451909] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)37.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)36.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451927] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)35.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)34.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)33.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451953] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)32.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451965] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)31.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451974] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)30.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451983] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)29.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.451992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)28.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)27.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452007] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)26.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452014] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)25.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)24.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452029] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)23.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)22.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)21.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452050] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)20.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452060] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)19.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)18.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452079] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)17.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452086] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)16.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452095] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)15.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)14.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452114] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)13.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452123] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)12.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452133] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)11.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452142] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)10.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)9.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)8.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452175] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)7.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452183] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)6.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452193] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)5.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)4.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452211] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)3.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452219] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)2.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)1.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452236] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)0.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.452237] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    3.452240] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: (efault)0
[    3.452241] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: (efault)128
[    3.452242] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:6074]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1106208 Jul 17 16:05 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1103952 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1209628 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1223144 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1300764 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053156 Jul 17 16:05 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053004 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1147104 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1163672 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1226208 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1106228 Jul 17 16:05 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1103968 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1209644 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1223160 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1300780 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053176 Jul 17 16:05 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053020 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1147120 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1163688 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1226224 Jun 22 14:55 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-59.ucode

/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0:
total 4284
drwxr-xr-x  2 maxg maxg    4096 Jul  2  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 95 root root   36864 Jul 18 17:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 1106208 Jul  2  2019 iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 1053156 Jul  2  2019 iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 1106228 Jul  2  2019 iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 1053176 Jul  2  2019 iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg    2041 Jul  2  2019 LICENSE.iwlwifi-Qu.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg    4738 Jul  2  2019 README.iwlwifi-Qu.ucode
```

Edit:

```
  ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 maxg maxg 1106228 Jul 19 17:42 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1103952 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1209628 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1223144 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1300764 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1329296 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1334856 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-63.ucode
-rw-rw-r-- 1 maxg maxg 1052796 Jul 19 17:42 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053004 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1147104 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1163672 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1226208 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1248672 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1252748 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-63.ucode
-rw-rw-r-- 1 maxg maxg 1106248 Jul 19 17:42 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1103968 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1209644 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1223160 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1300780 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1329312 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1334872 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-63.ucode
-rw-rw-r-- 1 maxg maxg 1052816 Jul 19 17:44 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053020 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1147120 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1163688 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1226224 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1248688 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1252764 Jul 18 17:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-63.ucode

/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0:
total 4284
drwxr-xr-x  2 maxg maxg    4096 Jul  2  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 94 root root   36864 Jul 19 17:30 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 1106208 Jul  2  2019 iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 1053156 Jul  2  2019 iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 1106228 Jul  2  2019 iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 1053176 Jul  2  2019 iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg    2041 Jul  2  2019 LICENSE.iwlwifi-Qu.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg    4738 Jul  2  2019 README.iwlwifi-Qu.ucode
```

Edit

```
 dkms status
backport-iwlwifi, 8613, 5.11.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127713/discussion-on-question-by-newtoubuntu-intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubun).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with the iwlwifi kernel module. It doesn't recognize the latest Intel AX201 modem card. Why? Because iwlwifi isn't coded for the device codes of the Intel AX201!

Let's patch the iwlwifi kernel module so that it works with the Intel AX201.

- Install Ubuntu 21.04
- Boot to the 5.11.0-2x kernel from the GRUB "Additional Options" menu
- Install `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

  - `sudo apt update`
  - `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`
  - This will fail to fully install on kernels > 5.4.0. This is expected.
  - This software installs source code into `/usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613`
- Edit the `dkms.conf` file in the source code directory `/usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613`

  - `sudo -H gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/dkms.conf`
  - Edit the file and change `OBSOLETE_BY="5.4.0"` to `#OBSOLETE_BY="5.4.0"`
- Edit the `drv.c` file in the source code directory `/usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie`

  - `sudo -H gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c`
  - Enable "Display line numbers" in Gedit preferences
  - Add the following line below the other 0xA0F0 ID lines at #447-#448...

    `IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x6074, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),`
- rebuild the patched dkms module

  - `sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/8613`
  - `sudo dkms add backport-iwlwifi/8613`
  - `sudo dkms build backport-iwlwifi/8613`
  - `sudo dkms install backport-iwlwifi/8613`
- reboot to the 5.11.0-2x kernel via GRUB, and retest the AX201
- purge the 5.13.4 kernel

  - `dpkg -l *5.13.4*` # list 4 linux* package names to purge
  - `sudo dpkg -P package_name#{1|2|3|4}` # do this for each of the four package names
- `sudo update-grub` # update GRUB
- reboot normally
- file a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu against package `linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-25-generic` running on a `Samsung Galaxy Book Flex2 Alpha`

**Note**: Currently installed AX201 firmware can be seen at `ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-*`

**Note**: If additional newer firmware code is required, see `https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-Qu-*`

**Note**: Newer kernels can be found at [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

**Sources**:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1977295
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1983607
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ohziei/cant_detect_wifi_adapter_on_samsung_galaxy_book/

**Co-credits**: @chili555

Comment: May I please get 7 1/2 points? ;-))

Comment: @chili555 At least you got co-credits :-)

Comment: Thanks !!! @heynnema I'm also samsung galaxy flex2(uses wifi adapter AX-201) user and I got same problem... Your answer saved me When I saw wifi-list I really thrilled and screamed T.T I love you !!!! I would like to comment for the next user.
I installed ubuntu 21.04 on 080821, but kernel 5.11.0-16 was built-in. I couldn't find 5.11.0-2x any where, so I used 5.11.1 and it worked.(5.11.16 or 5.13.8 won't work!)

Comment: @heynnema do you happen to know if this also works for AX-210 or what needs to be changed to get it working?  
I suspect the addition "IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x6074, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL)," might need to be different?

Comment: @ThomasArildsen See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356118/ax210-wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu21-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update

Comment: If i understand correctly, this seems to be still an issue on 5.19

Comment: Placing this here for future reference. For me, the issue was solved by updating the Linux kernel to v6.4. None of the other steps were required.