# When will Ubuntu natively support Intel Wi-fi 6 AX201?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, permissions

I was having issues with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I could not connect to the internet. The only way I was able was through connecting my phone to my laptop so that my laptop could share off the wifi. When I looked at the wifi menu in settings, the menu would say something like, "Adapter not found".

SOOOO....

I decided to try Kali. I was eventually able to get Kali up and working, but same exact deal as Ubuntu.

I'm assuming that this is happening across both OSs because they both run off of Debian. I've also done some digging through other posts on this very topic and it appears that this is the problem. I've tried following dozens of posts, but none of them have worked.

I think that because the  Intel Wi-fi 6 AX201 is relatively new, Ubuntu and others have not yet built native support for it.

When will native Wi-fi 6 AX201 compatibility come to Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried 21.04?

Comment: Please see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04/1353300#1353300

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I did upgrade to 21.04, but unfortunately, I'm still seeing the issue. I generally suck at linux compared to you and the rest of the geniuses on here haha, so I think I'll just take the L and either get a new machine or use an ethernet cable, since that is still working. Thanks 1 million for your help, though!!!!!!!!!! How can we best push Canonical to update their software so we can use this driver?????

Comment: As per my answer, above, it's a problem with the iwlwifi driver. However my answer isn't fully working yet. So either get an external USB wireless adapter, or use ethernet.

Comment: You could log a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: Please see my answer. I think that I've fixed the problem with it. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @Harrison Do you still need help... or not?