# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS stopped recognizing WiFi adapter

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 20.04, iwlwifi

I'm having issues to make Ubuntu recognize my wifi adapter which was working just fine. The issue started after the following 2 actions:

- Ubuntu update that ended up updating the firmware (my laptop is a Dell Precision 5550).
- Booting Windows 10 that I have in a separate partition and that I haven't used in a while.

So the sequence of actions was:

- Working on Ubuntu, Network working fine. Installed Ubuntu update which required a restart.
- I restarted the laptop since I needed to test something in my Windows partition so that also triggered the Firmware update which ended correctly.
- Accessed Windows partition. Network there works fine, so I don't think is a hardware issue. Restarted laptop.
- Logged into Ubuntu and then realized that the Network was not working.

So, I can't tell if the network issue started because of the firmware update or logging into Windows.
I tried multiple fixes but nothing seems to solve the issue.

What I find very confusing is that if I boot Ubuntu from a usb drive, the Network still doesn't work there (which was working fine).

The result of runinng `$ sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:604b11c000-604b11ffff
```

Which seems to mean that the drivers for my wifi card are installed.

Can anyone think what could be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: When dual-booting with Windows, disabling its Fast Startup feature is a MUST. That alone can prevent proper hardware initialization when rebooting to another OS. Shutting down Windows instead of rebooting typically don't have the same problem.

Comment: You probably have some missing firmware. Although it's not exactly the same as your problem, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04 and note some of the firmware related questions and commands. Maybe you can add similar commands/output into your question. You may just need to add some .ucode firmware files.

Comment: Thanks both. I tried disabling the Fast Startup and didn't fix the issue. I didn't get to try the missing firmware fix since the WIFI started to work again without me doing anything. I believe it had something to do with Windows preventing the proper hardware initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed on its own. I believe it had something to do with Windows preventing the proper hardware initialization. However, I'm unsure why it took 2 days to fix itself, plus I haven't logged into Windows recently.

Answer (score 0):

Check these settings in Windows. It may fix the problem permanently for you.

**Windows**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C: