# Missing WiFi adapter Intel AX201 on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 21.04, iwlwifi

I recently got sent a Dell Latitude 5510 from work, and it came with Windows 10. While in Windows, wifi works without problems. When I tried installing Ubuntu, the wifi adapter was not detected during install nor after.
I used a wired connection to install, but the wifi adapter was not detected after the install either.

dmesg shows no errors:

```
$ sudo dmesg -T | grep iwl
[mar sep 14 15:12:44 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[mar sep 14 15:12:44 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[mar sep 14 15:12:44 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[mar sep 14 15:12:44 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[mar sep 14 15:12:44 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
```

But the card doesn't show up in ip l and ubuntu also says there are no wireless adapters.

I'm using kernel version **5.11.0-34-generic**

Some extra info:

```
$ lspci -nnk
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi [8086:02f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0               
       description: Network controller
       product: Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:9133c000-9133ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (10) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 00
       serial: 74:78:27:7b:33:a0
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-34-generic firmware=0.6-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:126 memory:91300000-9131ffff
```

I've tried upgrading to 20.10, using the latest firmware, installing backport-iwlwifi-dkms. Nothing worked so far.
Right now I'm using a clean install with everything updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 is not working on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04)

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: "*doesn't seem to work*" too vague to offer useful advice. But that link is the answer: Blame Intel for not contributing the driver to the Linux kernel in a timely manner. Whether you choose to compile the driver in that answer or to buy a different WiFi dongle is up to you.

Comment: Is Fast Boot disabled in Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: First time I tried I wiped Windows and installed ubuntu over it. Wifi didn't work.

Now I installed Windows again, disabled fast boot, disabled wifi card in windows. Didn't seem to change anything