# Intel AX201 WiFi card not recognized

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have a Samsung Galaxy Book Flex2 Alpha with an Intel AX201 WiFi card dualbooting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 (now 21.04). In Windows, the WiFi card works just fine, but it doesn't work in Ubuntu.

`lspci` and `lshw` both recognize it.

I have tried disabling Windows' "fast boot" feature, as well as using version 21.04. I also `apt upgrade`d `linux-firmware`, with no useful results. `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` shows a message like `No suitable firmware found!`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you very much. I'm a total Linux noob, but I'm comfortable with the Unix shell.

#### Edit:

##### `ls -al /boot`

```
total 161996
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Sep 18 18:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 Sep 18 17:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   252994 Apr 14 12:31 config-5.11.0-16-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   253064 Aug 26 11:11 config-5.11.0-34-generic
drwx------  5 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Sep 18 17:22 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Sep 18 17:21 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.11.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 61665417 Sep 18 18:41 initrd.img-5.11.0-16-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 61691353 Sep 18 18:41 initrd.img-5.11.0-34-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Sep 18 17:17 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.11.0-16-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5968084 Apr 14 12:31 System.map-5.11.0-16-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5973530 Aug 26 11:11 System.map-5.11.0-34-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Sep 18 17:21 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.11.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14732384 Apr 20 04:13 vmlinuz-5.11.0-16-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 14752320 Aug 26 11:29 vmlinuz-5.11.0-34-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Sep 18 17:21 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.11.0-16-generic
```

##### `dkms status`

```
backport-iwlwifi, 8613, 5.11.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed
```

##### `modinfo iwlwifi`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-16-generic/updates/dkms/iwlwifi.ko
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
license:        GPL
author:         Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-mr-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-57.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-57.ucode
srcversion:     ED4BD9B69E28F43AB437F6B

---snipped, see previous edits---

depends:        compat,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.11.0-16-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         ubuntu Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        1A:99:03:76:D5:67:5F:C3:82:6C:33:86:8B:67:5E:40:9D:00:FA:1D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      1C:3C:D8:5B:74:91:ED:82:50:29:6C:86:5E:6A:59:0A:48:8A:8D:D9:
        AF:4C:25:A6:B4:A7:84:DF:18:34:16:03:52:0E:71:76:27:EC:A1:26:
        56:82:E0:EF:B0:A6:B4:39:00:DD:CC:55:21:DA:1A:15:58:52:AF:F4:
        B4:9B:36:52:55:B0:43:D8:D3:09:C5:9F:76:FC:32:50:7E:71:FE:91:
        BD:BD:9E:DA:E6:3D:54:C7:47:92:15:C5:DE:04:2D:68:37:28:78:40:
        DC:27:54:F8:CC:2F:6E:B5:98:B9:59:F1:CE:29:5B:51:B8:04:F7:3C:
        43:D0:A6:57:7E:72:B8:32:92:A9:97:85:56:E9:A6:0E:B4:75:53:7C:
        05:9B:B9:BA:1F:98:AB:91:96:B5:F6:8A:97:52:7A:14:9F:1D:7C:44:
        4C:38:52:BF:31:13:32:73:F0:AA:AA:CC:BB:7A:8C:8F:DC:CB:90:5B:
        F5:FB:93:DC:B9:D9:8D:EE:04:E7:1A:2D:65:5E:24:72:E6:A5:6B:E2:
        DA:C4:83:21:43:11:DE:AF:36:66:07:C5:27:E2:98:D2:E1:F9:0E:92:
        8F:6E:04:61:1E:73:3D:C5:EC:0F:7E:D1:40:A4:65:2A:DB:EE:EC:7B:
        FA:70:19:6F:0C:A0:F3:E4:48:D7:0B:2D:69:FC:FA:D8
parm:           debug:debug output mask (uint)
parm:           xvt_default_mode:xVT is the default operation mode (default: false) (bool)
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_msix:Disable MSI-X and use MSI instead (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
```

#### Edit 2

##### drv.c

```
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x43F0, 0x0078, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x43F0, 0x007C, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x43F0, 0x2074, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x43F0, 0x4070, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x0070, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x0074, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x0078, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x007C, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x0A10, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x1651, killer1650s_2ax_cfg_qu_b0_hr_b0, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x1652, killer1650i_2ax_cfg_qu_b0_hr_b0, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x2074, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x4070, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    // START AJS256 CHANGES
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x6074, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
    // END CHANGES
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x0070, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x0074, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x0078, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x007C, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x0310, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x1651, iwl_ax1650s_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x1652, iwl_ax1650i_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x2074, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x02F0, 0x4070, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x0070, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x0074, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x0078, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x007C, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x0310, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x1651, iwl_ax1650s_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x1652, iwl_ax1650i_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x2074, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x06F0, 0x4070, iwl_ax201_cfg_quz_hr, NULL),
    IWL_DEV_INFO(0x34F0, 0x0070, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),
```

##### `syslog`

```
Sep 18 17:26:29 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.151659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep 18 17:26:29 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.187710] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
Sep 18 17:26:29 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.202378] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
Sep 18 18:43:15 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.113952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep 18 18:43:15 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.131228] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
Sep 18 18:43:15 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.150043] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.060787] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)128.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078341] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)127.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078353] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)126.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078367] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)125.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)124.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078466] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)123.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)122.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078488] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)121.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078500] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)120.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)119.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)118.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)117.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)116.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)115.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)114.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078667] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)113.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078680] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)112.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)111.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078707] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)110.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)109.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078730] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)108.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078743] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)107.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)106.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078768] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)105.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)104.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078793] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)103.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078805] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)102.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078817] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)101.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)100.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)99.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078853] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)98.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078866] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)97.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)96.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078899] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)95.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078910] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)94.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)93.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)92.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)91.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078953] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)90.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078964] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)89.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078975] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)88.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078986] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)87.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.078997] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)86.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079007] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)85.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079018] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)84.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079029] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)83.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)82.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)81.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079068] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)80.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)79.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079096] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)78.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079109] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)77.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079122] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)76.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079135] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)75.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079146] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)74.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)73.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079171] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)72.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)71.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)70.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079208] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)69.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079221] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)68.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079233] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)67.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)66.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)65.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079273] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)64.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079292] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)63.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)62.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)61.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)60.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)59.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079370] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)58.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)57.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079397] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)56.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)55.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079420] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)54.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)53.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)52.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)51.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079468] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)50.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)49.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079492] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)48.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)47.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079517] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)46.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)45.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079541] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)44.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079552] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)43.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079564] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)42.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079576] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)41.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079591] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)40.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079605] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)39.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)38.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079631] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)37.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)36.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)35.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079668] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)34.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079680] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)33.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079692] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)32.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079705] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)31.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079719] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)30.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)29.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079743] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)28.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079756] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)27.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079767] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)26.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079779] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)25.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079792] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)24.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)23.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079816] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)22.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079828] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)21.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)20.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079853] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)19.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079865] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)18.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)17.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)16.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079911] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)15.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079923] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)14.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079935] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)13.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079947] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)12.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079959] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)11.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079971] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)10.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079985] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)9.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.079997] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)8.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080009] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)7.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)6.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080034] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)5.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)4.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)3.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080069] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)2.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080081] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)1.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080094] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)0.ucode failed with error -2
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080095] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080098] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: (efault)0
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080100] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: (efault)128
Sep 18 18:45:25 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.080101] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
Sep 18 18:49:46 lap-ubuntu dbus-daemon[20011]: [session uid=0 pid=20009] Activating service name='org.a11y.Bus' requested by ':1.1' (uid=0 pid=20005 comm="gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/dkms.conf " label="unconfined")
Sep 18 18:49:46 lap-ubuntu dbus-daemon[20011]: [session uid=0 pid=20009] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=20005 comm="gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/dkms.conf " label="unconfined")
Sep 18 19:51:27 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.013496] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep 18 19:51:27 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.019135] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
Sep 18 19:51:27 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.020289] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
Sep 18 19:50:50 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.061994] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep 18 19:50:50 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.063454] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
Sep 18 19:50:50 lap-ubuntu kernel: [    3.064832] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
Sep 18 19:52:34 lap-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1923]: [session uid=0 pid=1921] Activating service name='org.a11y.Bus' requested by ':1.1' (uid=0 pid=1917 comm="gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/drivers/net/w" label="unconfined")
Sep 18 19:52:34 lap-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1923]: [session uid=0 pid=1921] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=1917 comm="gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/drivers/net/w" label="unconfined")
```

##### dkms.conf lines

```
#OBSOLETE_BY="5.4.0"
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04

Comment: Hi @heynnema, thanks for your reply. I was trying to follow your instructions, but I got caught up on the “dkms build” step. It’s saying that “make” exited 2. I looked at the log file, and it looks like there are some “implicit function declaration of function “kzfree”” errors. Do I need to try with 21.04?

Comment: Yes. 21.04 was step #1.

Comment: Sorry for not noticing that! I followed the steps there, but it’s still not working. Notably, backport-iwlwifi-dkms did install normally, and I see only kernel versions 5.11.0-34 and 5.11.0-16. I used the latter.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot` and `dkms status` and `modinfo iwlwifi`. Select the pasted text and then click the {} icon to format the text. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema just did that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The `modinfo` command didn't show me what I needed to see. So show me the drv.c file where you added the line... and include about 10 lines above and 10 lines below the edit (21 lines total). Show me `grep -i iwlwifi /var/log/syslog`. Why did you dkms build on kernel -16 instead of -34?

Comment: And show me `grep -i OBSOLETE_BY /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613/dkms.conf`

Comment: > Why did you dkms build on kernel -16 instead of -34? - because that was the "other one" from the default, and I used that one since I didn't see -2x. Files forthcoming later.

Comment: I'm told that this won't work with the -16 kernel. Boot to the -34 kernel and do the dkms commands again, and then do `dkms status` again to make sure it got built/installed correctly on -34. Then reboot and retest.

Comment: I'm off to bed now, and will check in tomorrow.

Comment: It's not finding the AX201 firmware .ucode files. Install `linux-firmware` and add the firmware files from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html with `sudo cp`. Then reboot.

Comment: I assume that you added the two comments, "// START AJS256 CHANGES" and "// END CHANGES" to drv.c. I'm not 100% sure that's the correct format, so I'd remove those lines. Then do the dkms commands again. Remember to start comments to me with @heynnema

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!! All I had to do was enroll the MOK encryption key after the reboot (for some reason, it wasn't automatic). Thank you so much for your help @heynnema!

Comment: Great news! After making the various mods, was it the Intel firmware that was the final missing piece? Please make a "it worked for me" comment, and upvote my answer on the other question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running on the -34 kernel now?

Comment: @heynnema I think the MOK was the problem. Yes, I am using the -34 kernel now. I don't have enough reputation to upvote or comment on your answer, but I would.