# Wifi not working Ubuntu impish 21.10 Kernel 5.13.0 Samsung Galaxy Book Flex2

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, iwlwifi, 21.10

community,

i get a **Galaxy Book Flex2** (NP930QCA-KA3DE) from work. Windows goes completely to trash :), formated the whole disk and installed Ubuntu imprish.

Wifi don't work as you see in the logs and i can't find any other solution in the internet and posts here. Tried some thinks like install kernel 5.14 from kernel.ubuntu or installing the "hwe-edge kernel" but it doesnt help. Im again on 5.13.0 imprish standard.
So i wanted to ask your for help step by step so that we can help other too to bring the machine like this working.

Should i have to install the 5.15 kernel?

Here are my logs and harware posts:

##### sudo dmesg |grep iwlwifi | wc -l

```
3
```

##### inxi -Fxxxrz

```
System:    Kernel: 5.13.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Console: tty pts/1 wm: gnome-shell 
           DM: GDM3 41.rc Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: SAMSUNG product: 930QCA v: P09AJN serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 31 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: SAMSUNG model: NP930QCA-KA3DE v: SGLA830A0H-C01-G001-S0001+10.0.19042 serial: <filter> 
           UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: P09AJN.047.210930.MK date: 09/30/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 44.0 Wh (64.9%) condition: 67.8/67.0 Wh (101.1%) volts: 15.6 min: 15.4 
           model: SAMSUNG Electronics SR Real Battery type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Discharging cycles: 2 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 cache: 
           L1: 320 KiB L2: 8 MiB L3: 8 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38707 
           Speed: 861 MHz min/max: 400/4200 MHz volts: 0.7 V ext-clock: 100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 861 2: 912 3: 879 
           4: 569 5: 505 6: 808 7: 586 8: 544 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Samsung Co driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           chip-ID: 8086:9a49 class-ID: 0300 
           Device-2: Generic 720p HD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-6:4 chip-ID: 2b7e:0134 class-ID: 0e02 
           serial: <filter> 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.21.1.2 compositor: gnome-shell driver: loaded: i915 note: n/a (using device driver) 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz s-dpi: 96 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.2 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: Samsung Co driver: N/A bus-ID: 00:05.0 chip-ID: 8086:9a19 class-ID: 0480 
           Device-2: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Samsung Co driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 
           bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0c8 class-ID: 0401 
           Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-20-generic running: yes 
           Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
           Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: N/A port: 3000 bus-ID: 00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0f0 class-ID: 0280 
           IF-ID-1: usb0 state: unknown speed: -1 duplex: half mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-2: wwan0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Bluetooth: Device-1: Samsung GT-I9070 (network tethering USB debugging enabled) type: USB driver: rndis_host v: kernel 
           bus-ID: 2-1:5 chip-ID: 04e8:6864 class-ID: 0a00 serial: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:5 chip-ID: 8087:0026 class-ID: e001 
           Report: ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2 sub-v: 27a4 hci-v: 5.2 rev: 27a4 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 26.2 GiB (11.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZ9LQ256HAJD-000 size: 238.47 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 
           type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: FXV70K0Q temp: 29.9 C scheme: GPT 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 233.18 GiB used: 26.19 GiB (11.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 5.2 MiB (1.0%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0 C mobo: 42.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:     Packages: 1855 apt: 1848 snap: 7 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           1: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted
           2: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted
           3: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish universe
           4: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates universe
           5: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish multiverse
           6: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates multiverse
           7: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           8: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish partner
           9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main restricted
           10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security universe
           11: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security multiverse
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list 
           1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-impish.list 
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-impish.list 
Info:      Processes: 285 Uptime: 29m wakeups: 5656 Memory: 15.31 GiB used: 1.78 GiB (11.6%) Init: systemd v: 248 
           runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.2.0 alt: 11 Shell: sh (sudo) default: Bash v: 5.1.8 running-in: gnome-terminal 
           inxi: 3.3.06
```

##### lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:6074]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a0e8] (rev 20)
```

#### mokutil --sb-state

```
SecureBoot disabled
```

#### rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

#### sudo lshw -c network

```
  *-network UNGEFORDERT     
       Beschreibung: Network controller
       Produkt: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 14.3
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.3
       Version: 20
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       Konfiguration: latency=0
       Ressourcen: iomemory:600-5ff memory:603e194000-603e197fff
```

#### apt info linux-firmware | grep Version

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Version: 1.201
```

#### lsmod | grep iwlwifi

```
iwlwifi               376832  0
cfg80211              892928  1 iwlwifi
```

##### modinfo iwlwifi | grep -i version

```
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9340:55438a77
srcversion:     AD96E4B93D6EAEDECF9FBE5
vermagic:       5.13.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

#### modprobe iwlwifi

#### dmesg | grep -i iwl

```
[    6.274532] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.275582] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
[    6.297736] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

#### dkms status

```
backport-iwlwifi, 9340, 5.13.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed
```

#### ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi*.p*

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41804 Okt 23 13:46 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27480 Okt 23 13:46 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
```

echo end

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi*.p*`. Why did you install backport-iwlwifi?

Comment: Yikes! Let's try again: Please do: `sudo purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms ` Reboot and then show us: sudo dmesg | grep iwl Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema and @chili555 thank for your answers, i do first purge the `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` an do `ls /lib/firmware/iwlwifi*`.

Comment: @heynnema i did install backport-iwlwifi becouse as a soulution from another post, but dont helped.

Comment: I don't see `ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi*.p*`

Comment: @heynnema you was too fast. right now it is there

Comment: @chili555 after `purge backport...` and restart `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`
`[   12.604111] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.614151] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
[   12.625543] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Uninstall this...**

`sudo apt-get purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

`dkms status` # should no longer show backport-iwlwifi

`reboot`

**We'll rename these two files...**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41804 Okt 23 13:46 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27480 Okt 23 13:46 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
```

`cd /lib/firmware`

`sudo mv iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.HOLD`

`sudo mv iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.HOLD`

`reboot`

Retest networking.

**Update #1:**

**Note**: Excerpt/edited from [Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 is not working on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04)

The problem is with the iwlwifi kernel module. It doesn't recognize the latest Intel AX201 modem card. Why? Because iwlwifi isn't coded for the device codes of the Intel AX201!

Let's patch the iwlwifi kernel module so that it works with the Intel AX201.

- (re)Install `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

  - `sudo apt update`
  - `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`
  - This will fail to fully install on kernels > 5.4.0. This is expected.
  - This software installs source code into `/usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-9340`
- Edit the `dkms.conf` file in the source code directory `/usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-9340`

  - `sudo -H gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-9340/dkms.conf`
  - Edit the file and change `OBSOLETE_BY="5.4.0"` to `#OBSOLETE_BY="5.4.0"`
- Edit the `drv.c` file in the source code directory `/usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-9340/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie`

  - `sudo -H gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-9340/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c`
  - Enable "Display line numbers" in Gedit preferences
  - Add the following line below the other 0xA0F0 ID lines at #447-#448...

    `IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x6074, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),`
- rebuild the patched dkms module

  - `sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/9340`
  - `sudo dkms add backport-iwlwifi/9340`
  - `sudo dkms build backport-iwlwifi/9340`
  - `sudo dkms install backport-iwlwifi/9340`
- reboot normally

Retest networking.

Comment: it dont help: here my actual status:
`dkms status` -> nothing and 
`sudo dmesg | grep iwl`
`[    6.114051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.116601] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
[    6.142198] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
`

Comment: @scoop They may have regressed this in 21.10. So do the mods in my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04. Ignore the kernel parts... just do the iwlwifi stuff.

Comment: do you mean `Install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` again till dkms modules or adding ``IWL_DEV_INFO(0xA0F0, 0x6074, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),?

Comment: @scoop Yes. We'll reinstall backport-iwlwifi-dkms, make some mods to the source code, dkms stuff, reboot.

Comment: @scoop You may have to change occurrences of 8613 to 9340 in the instructions...

Comment: i do `Install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` no error :) and restart and do `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`
`[    6.015298] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    6.015298] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9340:55438a77
[    6.062654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.067632] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev a0f0/6074, rev=0x354, rfid=0x10a100
[    6.070668] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
`

Comment: @scoop Did you make the mods to the source code?

Comment: no will do the changes in link to 9340, have to catch train

Comment: @scoop I've added the edited instructions to Update #1 in my answer. Should be easier for you now.

Comment: @scoop After removing backport-iwlwifi-dkms the first time, did you `reboot` afterwards and retest networking?

Comment: 1. yes i do reboot after removing backport-iwfwifi-dkms but no wifi adapter to see on network manager. 
2. i do your advices on update #1, but on file `/usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-9340/dkms.conf`  there was `OBSOLETE_BY="5.14.0"` so i dont know if the change was needed. But i changed as you said. Now i see the wifi adapter and connected to earth. thank you!!

Comment: @scoop Great news! Thanks for the update.

Comment: @scoop Keep an eye on /lib/firmware/*.pnvm files possibly returning after a future Software Update.

Comment: thank you for you adivices. But now i dont hear nothing from wired headphones. Should i open a new thread?

Comment: @scoop  Yes, open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

> No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-impish.list

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

Please stop using this PPA Repo. It contains obsolete OneDrive Client Software. Please install the client correctly by following these instructions: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md