# HP Prodesk 400 G7 Minitower Wifi not working on Ubuntu 21.10 nor 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, 21.10

We have recently purchased 24 computer of HP Prodesk 400 G7 for our lab, we have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Ubuntu 21.10 through bootable USB drive. But it is showing that `No Wifi Adapter found`. We have tried several solutions, but none have worked for me. I have used following terminal commands to see the network devices attached:

```
$ lshw -c network

WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.

*-network       
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.6
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
     logical name: eno1
     version: 00
     serial: 6c:02:e0:69:2c:a0
     size: 100Mbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic duplex=full firmware=0.4-4
ip=192.168.18.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
speed=100Mbit/s
     resources: irq:122 memory:f1000000-f101ffff WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

```
$ lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b43] (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] [8086:9bc5] (rev 05)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller [8086:06f9]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:06ed]
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM [8086:06ef]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller [8086:06e0]
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Keyboard and Text (KT) Redirection [8086:06e3]
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller [8086:06d2]
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0687]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS [8086:06c8]
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:06a3]
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller [8086:06a4]
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM [8086:0d4c]
```

```
$ sudo lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:009c Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:134a HP, Inc Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It does not showing the wifi hardware or network controller any where. I have also tried to install the wifi drivers and packages using accepted solution presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04) but all in vain. Need prophetic remarks on this issue how can i cater this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain why the solution in the post you linked to was "all in vain"? Were you receiving error messages? If so, what were the exact messages? The AX201 does not seem to be in your `lspci` output. Do you see it if you run `sudo lspci` or `sudo lsusb` without any filters?

Comment: I have tried with `sudo` but the output was same with no network controller i.e. `AX201` I was landed on the mentioned solution because i have read the specification of our minitower system and there it was mentioned that the wifi chipset that is embedded is `intel wifi AX201` and then i molded my search query accordingly and find that solution but no hardware detected.

Comment: i have also edited the question and added output of `sudo lsusb`

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, I see zero evidence of a wireless network device in your computer. Silly question, but do you have a place for network antennas anywhere on the back of your HP cases?

Comment: @matigob The specs do indeed mention either an Intel AX201 (vPro or non vPro, whatever this means) or Realtek RTL8822CE (2x2 or 1x1 variants) and not as optional components. I would check UEFI just in case as it may came disabled by default.

Comment: Are you sure you bought the model that has wifi?  The product page shows wifi as an option

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i have examined the motherboard properly, and found that there is not hardware available inside the minitower box, while company keep claiming there is wifi hardware installed.  Hence concluded there was no wifi in this model only Ethernet.