# WiFi not working on Intel NUC - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

***Edit***
The answer provided by chili555 solved the issue and the wifi adapter now works

---

I'm trying to get Wifi working on an Intel NUC 13 with a Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i, 802.11ax card but it doesn't seem to be recognised.  I've tried upgrading to kernel 6.2.0 with no luck.

```
~sudo dmesg | grep iw
[    3.014195] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.016297] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 7af0/1692, rev=0x430, rfid=0x3010d000
[    3.016317] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

```
~lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7af0] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1692]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7acc] (rev 11)
```

```
~rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Wifi works fine in Windows and it appears the card should be supported.  I'm kind of at a loss about what to try next.  Any suggestions would be super helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I suspect this will help others with this new device.

Comment: My Intel NUC 13 works _much_ better after upgrading from 22.04 to 23.04. Notably: displays, hdmi audio, wifi.

Comment: @chili555 could you help me?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1495285/ax211ngw-not-working-on-ubuntu-23-10

Comment: @kob22 I've made a comment at your post. I'm on it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device is very new and is not yet covered in the current version of the driver *iwlwifi*. I suggest that we try a highly experimental process.

First, I recommend that you install Ubuntu 22.10 using a default 5.19.0-xx kernel version. Next, with a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

This takes a few moments, please be patient.

```
sudo nano -l /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-9904/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c
```

At line number 365, change the line:

```
IWL_DEV_INFO(0x7A70, 0x1692, iwlax411_2ax_cfg_so_gf4_a0, iwl_ax411_killer_1690i_name),
```

To read:

```
IWL_DEV_INFO(0x7AF0, 0x1692, iwlax411_2ax_cfg_so_gf4_a0, iwl_ax411_killer_1690i_name),
```

That is, you will change *only* 7A70 to 7AF0.

Proofread carefully twice, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x).

Now remove the old version:

```
sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/9904
```

And install the new version:

```
sudo dkms add backport-iwlwifi/9904
sudo dkms build backport-iwlwifi/9904
sudo dkms install backport-iwlwifi/9904
```

Reboot and show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

References: [Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 is not working on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04)

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/iwlwifi-not-working-in-manjaro-kde-221115-linux519/129578/5

Possibly needed firmware: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode

Comment: Just `sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` (and rebooting) may be enough for some cases (it was for me).

Comment: @chili555 Could you recommend linux-oem-22.04c kernel which has that line needed: https://git.launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+git/jammy/tree/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c?h=Ubuntu-oem-6.1-6.1.0-1021.21

Comment: @RA Please start your own new question and include: `uname -r` and: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I tried quite a bit but did not manage to resolve this issue following this answer of @chili555 . I asked a new question with details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487617/wifi-not-working-on-intel-nuc-tried-backport-iwlwifi-dkms