# Wifi not working on Intel NUC - tried backport-iwlwifi-dkms

Tags: wireless, kernel, 22.04, iwlwifi, intel-nuc

Similar to other users, I randomly started having wifi issues on my Intel NUC which is running Ubuntu 22.04. Note that the wifi card is fine, I have a dual-boot QubesOS which is having working internet access via that wifi.

I did follow the instructions of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1456701/499997) but still could not resolve it.

Here the steps to reproduce:

1. I manually installed kernel 5.19.0-051900-generic (I was on some 5.15 version previously, I also tried the latest 6.4 but got same results)
2. I installed backport-iwlwifi-dkms which was a major hassle as I was offline and had to manually copy all dependencies over via USB but seems to have gone fine despite some error for my 6.4 kernel that I cannot completely remove for some reason after installing backport-iwlwifi-dkms (weird but doesn't matter for now).
   [image]
3. I changed the file although the folder was called slightly differently, it seems to have worked:
   [image]
4. I then installed it as indicated in the other answer, seems to have gone well:
   [image]
5. Still the same issues then during reboot that I always encountered since this issue appeared:
   [image]
6. Finally all done but still no wifi, here the output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` as requested in the other answer:
   [image]

EDIT: as pointed out in the comment by A R, I do in fact run a AX201 so the instructions that I referred to in the other answer were probably not relevant.
[image]

Comment: Well the answer you referenced is for `AX1690i` and you seem to have `AX201`.

Comment: Post `lspci -nnk -d ::0280` command output to be sure what adapter you have

Comment: In terminal `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopt.conf` then reboot

Comment: Thank you @RA you were right, I have an `AX201`, I added a picture above.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I did what you suggested but it had no effect.