# AX211NGW not working on ubuntu 23.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, 23.10

I bought wifi card intel AX211NGW for dell optiplex 3000 thin client with intel n6005. I have ubuntu 23.10, and I cannot set up wifi. Why ubuntu shows this card as AX201? The card has the inscription AX211NGW

uname -r

```
uname -r
6.5.0-14-generic
```

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:4df0] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0094]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Management Engine Interface [8086:4de0] (rev 01)
```

sudo dmesg | grep iwl

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.342547] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.348474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x11219, cnv-id 0x20000302 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    2.348497] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev 4df0/0094, rev=0x351, rfid=0x2010d000
[    2.348514] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 4df0/0094, rev=0x351, rfid=0x2010d000
[    2.348597] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

and network

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6001124000-6001127fff
```

I tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/1456701 but its not working. How should I setup? @

Comment: I believe the latest version of `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` covers your device. Please try installing it, reboot and let us hear the result. https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/backport-iwlwifi-dkms Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 thanks for help, I already installed 11289 package  this before posting here, without result. 
sudo dmesg | grep iwl returns the same messages as without this package. 
Also I tried latest kernel 6.6 and still no success. 

I added similar line with IWL_DEV_INFO but I card was loaded but I did something wrong and WiFi didn’t work. Could you give me correct line and I will try? 
Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you change `IWL_DEV_INFO(0x4DF0, 0x0078, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),` to read: `IWL_DEV_INFO(0x4DF0, 0x0094, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL),` In other words, change 0x0078 to 0x0094. Then complete the process as before and reboot. Then show us: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Thanks @chili555 , I did it and its not working. I cannot paste logs here, because it was too long. 

Here is log for AX201:
https://pastebin.com/w8sw5PZW


Why AX201? The card is 100% AX211NGW, so I removed this previous line and I added this line:
`IWL_DEV_INFO(0x4DF0, 0x0094, iwlax211_2ax_cfg_so_gf_a0, NULL),`

Here is log with this line:
    https://pastebin.com/VX0Rf2iq

What can I do?

Comment: I updated bios, and I have new log...

`[    2.337454] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.343745] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0xa5a5a5a2, cnv-id 0xa5a5a5a2 wfpm id 0xa5a5a5a2
[    2.343762] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Can't find a correct rfid for crf id 0x5a2
[    2.343830] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
`

Comment: Its weird, after this update everything changed... I paste log here from all commands:
https://pastebin.com/t6UWyaf4

Comment: Right now I have new log, the same as at the begining
`[    2.415298] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.423477] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x11219, cnv-id 0x20000302 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    2.423495] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev 4df0/0094, rev=0x351, rfid=0x2010d000
[    2.423499] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 4df0/0094, rev=0x351, rfid=0x2010d000
[    2.423531] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
`

Comment: "Why AX201? The card is 100% AX211NGW, so I removed this previous line and I added this line:" Because, in the driver code `drv.c`, your pci.id 4df0 is only listed as AX201. Furthermore, your own readings above say: "Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0094]" Please retry as ax201.

Comment: @chili555 ok, I set `IWL_DEV_INFO(0x4DF0, 0x0094, iwl_ax201_cfg_qu_hr, NULL)`, here is log: from 3 commands https://pastebin.com/45zuwUKa
So what can I do?

After that I inserted card intel AC 9560 from my laptop, wifi works, and look at log: https://pastebin.com/UG2xnNhB LSCPI says that card is AX201, on dmesg its ok and it is `[    3.136215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x351`

Comment: I am quickly running out of ideas. You might try a later kernel version, this perhaps: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.6.5/ Frankly, I'd stick with the 9560 and wait for support for your device.

Comment: I already checked, not working.